# How make elements from list to method attributes?

Tags: python

```
def cinput():
        temp = []
        print ("Input name: ")
        temp.append(input())
        print ("Input about: ")
        temp.append(input())
        return temp
    
class Person:
        def __init__(self,Name,About):
            self.Name  = Name
            self.About = About
    
new_friend = Person(cinput())
```

how to make this code work?without changes in class Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```py
new_friend = Person(*cinput())
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```py
temp_input = cinput()
new_friend = Person(temp_input[0], temp_input[1])
```

That is, `*` "unpacks" the list (or iterables) and seperately use each element as an argument.